# How To Properly Characterize Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm on a course of self-study and am working to properly understand and characterize some concepts I am exploring with respect to vectors and the geometry related to their addition. My aim is to make sure the language I use is precise. I put "quotes" around terms I am using that I am uncertain are the accurate terms to use.

Suppose I have two vectors $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb R^N_+$ and $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb R^N_+$. Vector addition is of course $\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{c}$. However, suppose the individual vectors, $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are in a different "vector space". To be concrete and a bit simplistic, let $\mathbf{a}$ be a vector of person heights in meters and let $\mathbf{b}$ denote their weight in kilograms. Then, the resulting $\mathbf{c}$ would be nonsense as they both "span" a different space.

Nonetheless, suppose some composite of the two is still wanted, maybe where the resulting composite is $.7\mathbf{a} + .3\mathbf{b}$.

Before creating the composite, I believe both vectors need to be on the same "plane". Suppose I use [feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#:%7E:text=Feature%20scaling%20is%20a%20method,during%20the%20data%20preprocessing%20step.) to transform the elements of each vector to be on the [0,1] space such that the max value in the vectors is 1 and the least is 0.

This transform places them both in the same vector space as they now both span the same space and now the scalars can be applied to each vector and a composite created. Now, they share a common metric (both on the unit space).

Silliness of the example used ignored, is this a correct way to characterize the problem? How else might this type of problem be conveyed using mathematically correct language?

Comment: When we say a vector space is closed under addition and scalar multiplication it means all possible linear combinations of those vectors are also vectors in the space. So it's part of the axioms that they can't be in different spaces. Closure is really important which is why it's demanded.

Comment: Adding different physical units only makes sense if they are converted to the same units. Compare that to common denominators in mathematics. If you want to add a two dimensional vector to a three dimensional vector, for example, then you would convert the two dimensional vector to a three dimensional vector by adding a zero as the third coordinate.

Comment: What does the $+$ mean in $\mathbb R^N_+$?

Comment: @paul, I use $\mathbb R^N_+$ to mean a positive real number of length $N$.

Comment: @dhc Okay, you should explain this in your question. The notation is unusual,  by $\mathbb R^N$ one normally understands the $N$-dimensional Euclidean space.

Answer (score 2):

There is a construction called the direct product that allows unrelated vector spaces to be combined into a super space.

Vector spaces do not have maximum values, they continue infinitely in every direction that they span.

in general, a vector space is an abstract object, it can be any kind of space that supports addition and multiplication by scalars.

so, for example, pairs of real numbers can be a vector space, but so could scalar functions on a particular domain, or more abstract constructions like the direct product, or the tensor product, or a quotient.